# Why does DWORDLONG mem = 2048 *1024 * 1024; get maximum value?

Tags: c++

DWORDLONG is type defined as ULONGLONG in Visual Studio.
ULONGLONG is type defined as __int64.
mem gets 18446744073709551615 when I debug it.
It is maximum value of DWORDLONG.
It must have 2147483648.
What is wrong with my code?

edit)
DWORDLONG mem = 2048 *1024 * 1024L has the same problem.
So, How can I fix it?

Comment: If you want to ask *"What is wrong with my code?"*, you should ***show us your code***!

Comment: @abelenky The code is in the title of the question.

Comment: What you do with a value does not affect how it is computed. That you store it in a `DWORDLONG` doesn't affect the computation of the value in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `2048 * 1024 * 1024`, all the constants have type `int`, so the product is computed as an `int`. As `int`, the product is a signed arithmetic overflow, undefined behavior in theory and producing -2<sup>31</sup> in practice here. This number -2<sup>31</sup> is the one that gets converted to the type `DWORDLONG` to be assigned to `mem`.

The target type is a 64-bit unsigned type, so a negative value  of (comparatively small) magnitude is converted to value close to the maximum of the type. In the same way that -1 when converted to a `DWORDLONG` produces the value 2<sup>64</sup>-1,the value  -2<sup>31</sup> converted to `DWORDLONG` produces the value  2<sup>64</sup>-2<sup>31</sup>

You can make sure that the entire chain of operations is done in `DWORDLONG`, producing the correct result, by converting the first operand to `DWORDLONG`:

```
DWORDLONG mem = ((DWORDLONG)2048) * 1024 * 1024;
```

Answer (score 1):

The product is evaluated as a 32-bit integer, and overflows. Add an L to one of the factors.